# What about questions that only make sense because the querent lacks knowledge

Tags: discussion, questions

So, the question that inspired this is [Where does the number added to a roll for damage come from?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94086/where-does-the-number-added-to-a-roll-for-damage-come-from/94088#94088) .

The question is short, clear, and concise.  It's clear what the asker is confused about, and what sort of answer they expect.  This sort of question is normally an excellent fit for our site.

But wait!

The external reality the querent doesn't have access to does not correspond to the artificial facsimile of that reality that they have constructed in their head!  As a result, people who understand more than them about the subject or subjects to which their question pertains see the question as at best unanswerable and at worst nonsense.  However, without 'answering' in a way the erroneously grounded question they have formed, they will not be able to realize the truths that make said question poor.  What are we to do?

We can close questions like this as 'unclear what you're asking', which seems wrong because what they are asking is in no way unclear except for how we are to answer it

We can close questions like this as 'too broad', which seems wrong because the questions aren't phrased in any way broadly, they just have no clear answer because of some piece of information the querent lacks.

We can answer these questions by explaining the piece of information the querent is missing that makes their question problematic, but this seems wrong because it's often not a real answer to the question they are asking.

We can answer these questions by explaining the piece of information the querent is missing that makes their question problematic in a comment, but this seems wrong because comments are ephemeral and future querents with the same question are unlikely to benefit from this form of resolution.

Ideas?

Comment: I think this is another example of [How do we handle it when the asker's problem is just that they're confused?](//meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3505), which is about how to handle questions based on misconceptions. (The example here appears to be a #3.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Dang it!  I knew we already did this but I couldn't find it ^^; Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Asked and answered. :)